# Querying multiple time zones in Amazon Timestream

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, time-series, amazon-timestream

I have an application that stores telematics from vehicles across the USA.  The USA has multiple time zones and the vehicle can be active and move across time zones whilst active.  I want to be able to query 'yesterday' and calculate all the 'active time' all vehicles have been active for.

All 'time' in Amazon Timestream is stored in UTC as a timestamp so I cannot add the timezone offset to the time.

Raw data:

| vehicle | totalHours | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 10 | 2021-03-20T20:00:00 EST |
| abc | 20 | 2021-03-21T10:00:00 EST |
| abc | 30 | 2021-03-21T18:00:00 EST |
| def | 40 | 2021-03-21T02:00:00 EST |
| def | 50 | 2021-03-21T15:00:00 EST |
| def | 60 | 2021-03-21T20:00:00 EST |

Stored data:

| vehicle | measure_name | measure_value::double | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | totalHours | 10 | 2021-03-21 01:00:00 |
| abc | totalHours | 20 | 2021-03-21 15:00:00 |
| abc | totalHours | 30 | 2021-03-21 23:00:00 |
| def | totalHours | 40 | 2021-03-21 10:00:00 |
| def | totalHours | 50 | 2021-03-21 23:00:00 |
| def | totalHours | 60 | 2021-03-22 04:00:00 |

Query:

```
SELECT vehicle, SUM('measure_value::double') AS totalHours
FROM "Database"."Table" 
WHERE time BETWEEN '2021-03-18 00:00:00' AND '2021-03-18 23:59:59' AND  measure_name = 'totalHours'
GROUP BY vehicle
```

Expected:

| vehicle | totalHours |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 50 |
| def | 150 |

Returns:

| vehicle | totalHours |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 60 |
| def | 90 |

- If I query in UTC time, it will be 5-8 hours out of date.
- If I query in Eastern Time (UTC+5) then any vehicles running in California (UTC+8) will have their data up to 4 hours out.

How would I query yesterday in all time zones without querying all time zones independently?

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh - does the edit help?

Comment: @CarlThomas did you find an answer? I too am in need of more understanding of time zones in AWS Timestream databases.